# Using LabView to get title from HTTPS site?

Tags: https, labview

I would like to retrieve a HTTPS website's title using LabView.  There doesn't appear to be any examples using the LabVIEWHTTPClient.lvlib and I am struggling as to how to access data from an HTTPS site using this library.  No login is required to access this website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LabVIEW HTTP client is built on top of cURL and has https built in.

Just pass in the url starting with https:// and it will work just fine. I guess there could be an example but it wouldn't be any different than a non-https example.

You can take that body result and run it through a regex node to get the title:

[image: code snippet]

Produces the output:

```
Google
```